# Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading

I want to update some labels on my form (VB.NET) based on network change events. On one event it works perfectly, but the other raises this error:

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'lblHostnameT' accessed from
>   a thread other than the thread it was created on.

I'm writing a small application for network diagnostics. To notify user of network changes, I am using NetworkChange class.

On form load, event handlers are created:

```
AddHandler NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged, AddressOf NetworkAvailabilityChanged
AddHandler NetworkChange.NetworkAddressChanged, AddressOf NetworkAddressChanged
```

These are event handlers:

```
Private Sub NetworkAvailabilityChanged(sender As Object, e As NetworkAvailabilityEventArgs)
    ResetStats()
    niTray.ShowBalloonTip(5000)
End Sub

Private Sub NetworkAddressChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    ResetStats()
    niTray.ShowBalloonTip(5000)
End Sub
```

And this is ResetStats:

```
Private Sub ResetStats()
    lblHostnameT.Text = "[na]"
    lblIPT.Text = "[na]"
    lblGWT.Text = "[na]"
    lblDNST.Text = "[na]"
    lblGWPingT.Text = "[na]"
    lblDNSTestT.Text = "[na]"
    lblDCPingT.Text = "[na]"
    lblExtPingT.Text = "[na]"
    GWPingSent = 0
    GWPingReceived = 0
    GWAverage = 0
    DNSTestDone = 0
    DNSTestOK = 0
    DCPingSent = 0
    DCPingReceived = 0
    DCAverage = 0
    ExtPingSent = 0
    ExtPingReceived = 0
    ExtAverage = 0
    DCList.Clear()
    DCList.Add("192.168.19.113")
    DCList.Add("172.31.0.2")
    DCList.Add("172.31.0.3")
    DCList.Add("172.31.0.4")
    ExtList.Clear()
    ExtList.Add("www.google.com")
    ExtList.Add("www.msn.com")
    ExtList.Add("www.yahoo.com")
    DNSTestList.Clear()
    DNSTestList.Add("www.google.com")
    DNSTestList.Add("www.msn.com")
    DNSTestList.Add("www.yahoo.com")
    DNSTaskList.Clear()
    IPList.Clear()
    GWList.Clear()
    DNSList.Clear()
    lblHostnameT.Text = My.Computer.Name

    Dim nics() As NetworkInterface = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces
    Dim ipi As IPInterfaceProperties

    For Each nic As NetworkInterface In nics
        If (nic.OperationalStatus = OperationalStatus.Up) AndAlso (nic.NetworkInterfaceType <> NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback) Then
            ipi = nic.GetIPProperties()
            If (ipi IsNot Nothing) AndAlso (ipi.UnicastAddresses IsNot Nothing) AndAlso (ipi.UnicastAddresses.Count > 0) Then
                For Each iip As IPAddressInformation In ipi.UnicastAddresses
                    If iip.Address.AddressFamily = Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork Then
                        IPList.Add(iip.Address.ToString & " (" & nic.Name & ")")
                    End If
                Next
                If (ipi.GatewayAddresses IsNot Nothing) AndAlso (ipi.GatewayAddresses.Count > 0) Then
                    For Each iip As GatewayIPAddressInformation In ipi.GatewayAddresses
                        If iip.Address.AddressFamily = Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork Then GWList.Add(iip.Address.ToString)
                    Next
                End If
                If (ipi.DnsAddresses IsNot Nothing) AndAlso (ipi.DnsAddresses.Count > 0) Then
                    For Each iip As Net.IPAddress In ipi.DnsAddresses
                        If iip.AddressFamily = Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork Then DNSList.Add(iip.ToString)
                    Next
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
    lblIPT.Text = String.Join(", ", IPList.ToArray)
    niTray.Text = "NetInfo" & vbCrLf & lblHostnameT.Text & vbCrLf & lblIPT.Text
    lblGWT.Text = String.Join(", ", GWList.ToArray)
    If GWList.Count > 1 Then
        lblGWT.ForeColor = Color.Red
    Else
        lblGWT.ForeColor = Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText
    End If
    lblDNST.Text = String.Join(", ", DNSList.ToArray)
End Sub
```

When I change one NIC's connectivity (e.g. by switching WiFi SSID), NetworkAvailabilityChanged is fired and UI is updated fine. But when I make a change resulting in NetworkAddressChanged call (e.g. by plugging ethernet cable into laptop) the application crashes with the error, on first line of ResetStats. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UI controls have thread affinity; you can *only* touch them from the UI thread. Your network events *do not come from the UI thread*. The solution is to bounce the UI work to the UI thread. In C#, this would be something like:

```cs
// not shown prep work to figure out what to do
// string newLabel = ...
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate {
    // now we're on the UI thread
    someControl.Text = newLabel;
    // etc
});
```

My VB isn't strong enough to translate that, sorry.

If in doubt, you could bounce *the entire thing* to the UI thread, but it often makes sense to do the pre-processing on a worker thread. But:

```cs
private void NetworkAvailabilityChanged(object sender, NetworkAvailabilityEventArgs args)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { // jump to UI thread
            NetworkAvailabilityChanged(sender, args);
        });
    }
    else
    {
        // the real code
    }
}
```

Comment: I will check this. But my question is that why one of these events works fine (always) and the other doesn't (at all)?! They seam completely simillar.

Comment: @MohammadJavahery presumably one is invoked (by the caller, outside of your control) via sync-context, and the other doesn't?

Comment: I just came back to thank you for your help. I could use invoking by method mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invoke?view=netframework-4.8) and solve the problem.

Comment: I recommend to use ```BeginInvoke(..)``` instead (avoids dead-locks).